# Is there a way to have a choice command and a timer at the same time?

Tags: batch-file

Essentially, can you have these two sets of code happening on the same screen at the same time?

This:

```
@echo off
cls
choice /c 123 /n 
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto op1
if %errorlevel% == 2 goto op2
if %errorlevel% == 3 goto op3
```

And this:

```
@echo off
:var
cls
set /a num=%num%+1
echo %num%
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
goto var
```

This way there would be a timer at the top but you are still able to use a command.
It could also be helpful if there was a more efficient timer that didn't involve going back to the variable.

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `choice /?` and read the output help. `%SystemRoot%\System\choice.exe` (full qualified file name of this [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands)) supports itself a timeout. BTW: You can use after the command line with `choice` also `goto op%errorlevel%` and avoid the three `if` conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type `choice /?` to see your options as choice has a timeout option. The correct way to wait is either `choice`, `timeout`, or `waitfor` not `ping`.

**Getting Help**

For general help. Type `Help` in the command prompt. For each command listed type `help <command>` (eg `help dir`) or `<command> /?` (eg `dir /?`).

Some commands have sub commands. For example  `schtasks /create /?`.

The `NET` command's help is unusual. Typing `net use /?` is brief help. Type `net help use` for full help. The same applies at the root - `net /?` is also brief help, use `net help`.

References in Help to new behaviour are describing changes from CMD in OS/2 and Windows NT4 to the current CMD which is in Windows 2000 and later.